# Video is not working in react native(android)

Tags: react-native

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {AppRegistry,StyleSheet,Text,Alert,TouchableOpacity,View,ScrollView,Image,WebView,ListView,Linking } from 'react-native';

import Video from 'react-native-video';

 class SampleRow extends React.Component{

 constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.onLoad = this.onLoad.bind(this);
this.onProgress = this.onProgress.bind(this);
 }

 state = {
rate: 1,
volume: 1,
muted: false,
resizeMode: 'contain',
duration: 0.0,
currentTime: 0.0,
  };

 onLoad(data) {
this.setState({duration: data.duration});
  }

 onProgress(data) {
this.setState({currentTime: data.currentTime});
 }

  render() {
return (
  <View >
   <Video source={{uri:"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gQOaYQs07fc"}}
   style={styles.backgroundVideo}
 rate={this.state.rate} 
 volume={this.state.volume}
 muted={this.state.muted} 
 resizeMode={this.state.resizeMode} 
 onLoadStart={() => {console.warn("loading started");}} 
 onLoad={() => {console.warn("loading done");}} 
 onProgress={this.onProgress} 
 onEnd={() => { this.refs.myVideo.refs.node.seek(0) }} repeat={true}
   />
   </View>

    );
   }
  }

  var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  backgroundVideo: {
   position: 'absolute',
     top: 0,
    left: 0,
   bottom: 0,
  right: 0
   }
  });

 AppRegistry.registerComponent('smart', () => SampleRow);
```

Tried both local and remote video. Nothing works. Blank page in output.

Above code is reference from https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video/blob/master/example/index.android.js

Refereed here https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video/issues/174 but nothing helps

Expecting output like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TPGNgovQlRc

Comment: 'react-native-video' doesn't support youtube video urls. You can try this library https://github.com/inProgress-team/react-native-youtube which supports playing youtube videos.

Comment: @Jickson the local videos too not displayed

Comment: What is the url you are passing to play local video?

Comment: source={{uri:"./Videos/Videoname"}}

Comment: Try with source={require('./Videos/Videoname')} . This should work.

Comment: @Jickson it works. Do you know why geny motion remebers same output many times. That's why I can't able to see updated code changes. please let me know

Comment: Sorry. I am not aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

You should insert `width` and `height` in style.